# Write-Verbose Wrapper in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, overriding, wrapper, io-redirection

I have a script that uses `Write-Verbose` calls on it. I want to create a wrapper - override it, add another call, and then invoke the regular `Write-Verbose` command.

Something like:

```
Function global:Write-Verbose ($msg) {
    MyLogger $msg
    Real-Write-Verbose $msg
}
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible with `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand`:

```
function Write-Verbose {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
       [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
       [Alias('Msg')]
       [AllowEmptyString()]
       [System.String]
       ${Message})

    begin {
       try {
           $outBuffer = $null
           if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref]$outBuffer))
           {
               $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
           }
           $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Write-Verbose', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
           $scriptCmd = {& $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }
           $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
           $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
       } catch {
           throw
       }
    }

    process {
       try {
           MyLogger $Message
           $steppablePipeline.Process($_)
       } catch {
           throw
       }
    }

    end {
       try {
           $steppablePipeline.End()
       } catch {
           throw
       }
    }
}
```

Credit goes to  Joel Bennett@[Poshcode](http://poshcode.org/1744).

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to override it in your script scope (but not in any called scripts or functions), you can do it like this:

```
function Private:Write-Verbose ($msg) {
MyLogger $msg
&{Write-Verbose $msg}
}
```